# Delete hook incompatibility with delete function in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, post, hook, action

I have this action/hook:

```
add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'my_delete_function' );
 function my_delete_function($post_id) { 
    global $wpdb;
    $achievement = get_the_category($post_id); 
    $h = $achievement[0]->cat_ID; 
    $s = ''.str_replace('"', '', $h);
   if ( $s == 6 || $s == 5){
        $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM wp_votes WHERE post = ".$post_id) or die(mysql_error());

    }
}
```

The above works great when I am deleting posts from the admin. However, when the wp_delete_post() is called, the above function isnt called.

How can I make the action work with the delete function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to force it to delete. otherwise the `before_delete_post` hook is not executed.

```
 wp_delete_post( $postid, true);
```